# Choosing the date which is most recent for each ID number

Tags: r

I have `df` like this:

```
df <- data.frame(CustomerID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
                 Year = c(2012-02-03, 2012-03-05, 2013-10-22, 2014-03-02, 2015-02-19, 2016-11-20))
```

I want to choose the most recent date among each `CustomerID`.

My desired outcome is:

```
CustomerID  Latest Date
1           2013-10-22
2           2016-11-20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way with `dplyr` and `lubridate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(Year = as_date(Year)) %>% # Convert Year from character to Date (optional)
  group_by(CustomerID) %>%         # Group by CustomerID
  filter(Year == max(Year)) %>%    # Filter Year to return max Year of each group
  ungroup()                        # Ungroup
```

Alternatively:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Year = ymd(Year)) %>% # Convert Year from character to Date (optional)
  group_by(CustomerID) %>%     # Group by CustomerID
  arrange(desc(Year)) %>%      # Arrange Year in descending order
  slice(1) %>%                 # Slice/Take the first row of each group
  ungroup()                    # Ungroup
```

Both return:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  CustomerID Year      
       <dbl> <date>    
1       1.00 2013-10-22
2       2.00 2016-11-20
```

The data I'm using. Note that I've changed it a little by adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and making the `Year` var character. If you don't put quotes around the dates in `Year` it screws things up:

```
df <- data.frame(CustomerID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
                 Year = c("2012-02-03", 
                          "2012-03-05", 
                          "2013-10-22", 
                          "2014-03-02", 
                          "2015-02-19", 
                          "2016-11-20"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```